# Blazor, how to constantly get currentWindow width?

Tags: javascript, css, blazor

I want to do something like this in a razor page:

```
@if (currentwidth<x)
{
   le code
}
else
{
    le other code
}
```

I have added javascript file and connected it to a utility service which works when I get the static width (which I tested).

js:

```
export function getCurrentWidth() {

    return window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
        window.innerWidth;
    });

}
```

UtilityService method:

```
public async Task<double> GetCurrentWidth() 
        {
            var m = await GetModule();
            var result = await m.InvokeAsync<double>("getCurrentWidth");
            return result;
        }
```

Razor file:

```
double width;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        width = await utilityService.GetCurrentWidth();
    }
```

Thus the problem is I can't call it from OnInitailzedAsync since this function only fired once, so I need a function that constantly checks the GetCurrentWIdth() method to check for resize.

Is there another way of doing this in blazor or what method could I use/ Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all I'd like to point out that you may not have to solve your problem with javascript/C# code. If it's something in the html that you want to manipulate, you may just be better of using css. But I'll leave that up to you.

If however you truly need the window width like you mentioned above, then I would recommend registering a listener to the window (as you've already done) and have that listener call a dotnet function. Doing this with static methods is quite easy, but for instance component this can be a bit trickier as you have to pass an object reference of the current object.

The [JsInvokable] indicates that this method can be called from javascript, which allows communication from the javascript event listener to dotnet.

### CSharpFromJs.razor.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public partial class CSharpFromJS
{
    private DotNetObjectReference<CSharpFromJS> _objectReference;
    public int WindowWidth { get; set; }


    [Inject]
    public IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _objectReference = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await InitWindowWidthListener();
        }
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public void UpdateWindowWidth(int windowWidth)
    {
        WindowWidth = windowWidth;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private async Task InitWindowWidthListener()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("AddWindowWidthListener", _objectReference);
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("RemoveWindowWidthListener", _objectReference);
        _objectReference?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

### CSharpFromJs.razor

```
@implements IAsyncDisposable

<h1>Window width: @WindowWidth</h1>
```

### Javascript

```
// Manages the registered event listeners so they can be disposed later
let windowEventListeners = {};

function AddWindowWidthListener(objReference) {
    let eventListener = () => UpdateWindowWidth(objReference);
    window.addEventListener("resize", eventListener);
    windowEventListeners[objReference] = eventListener;
}

function RemoveWindowWidthListener(objReference) {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", windowEventListeners[objReference]);
}

function UpdateWindowWidth(objReference) {
    objReference.invokeMethodAsync("UpdateWindowWidth", window.innerWidth);
}
```

The only thing you should be careful with is when a component is disposd. You should remove the registered handlers in the DisposeAsync function to ensure that they're not still registered to prevent memory leaks.

[This link](https://code-maze.com/how-to-call-csharp-methods-from-javascript-in-blazor-webassembly/) might provide some better instructions on how to use this, but they don't explain the part about disposing handlers.

Note: This only works in .net5 and later, as IAsyncDisposable was not yet implemented for component before that. If for some reason you're working with an earlier version, you could call it using IDisposable. But this could potentially cause deadlocks, so I would not recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for this, it has helped me with a issue I was having too.

Comment: won't this dispose anyway without the js array caching? just _objectReference?.Dispose(); ?

Comment: That would indeed dispose the DotNetObjectReference itself, but not the handler configured in the javascript side. That needs to be disposes explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

For me works the NuGet package [BlazorPro.BlazorSize](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazorPro.BlazorSize)

Implement the method:

`async void WindowResized(object _, BrowserWindowSize window){}`

and all necessary Dependencies (see [description](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazorPro.BlazorSize)).

Comment: I need more information to make this work. Implement how?