# Blazor not updating from JS

Tags: blazor

I followed this tutorial which works perfectly https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/aspnet/blazor-tutorial/try

I ran into a issue though, I need to increment the counter from JavaScript, from an event from my service worker. If I use static interop the value in counter updates, but the UI doesn't display the update. I tried to change the interop to an instance method instead but cannot get that to work.

HTML

```
        const broadcast = new BroadcastChannel('count-channel');

        // Listen to the response
        broadcast.onmessage = (event) => {
            DotNet.invokeMethod('MyApp.Client', 'IncrementCount', 'no param');

            console.log("done");
        };
```

Razor

```
    @page "/counter"
    
    <h1>Counter</h1>
    
    <p>Current count: @currentCount</p>
    
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementMe">Click me</button>
    
    @code 
{
    static int currentCount = 0;
    
    public void IncrementMe()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public static void IncrementCount(string ignore)
    {
        currentCount++;
    }

}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, another way to test this would be to add a html button that calls a JavaScript function which attempts to execute the JSInvoke. It's almost like the method needs to be triggered on a UI thread or something for Razor to notice the change.

Comment: Use DotNetObjectReference. See this answer how to create and use this object: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68964761/6152891.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can pass instance to Javascript :

```
 private int currentCount = 0;

    private async Task IncrementCount()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("incrementCountFromJs", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this), nameof(JsMethod));
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public void JsMethod()
    {
        currentCount++;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

app.js:

```
function incrementCountFromJs(instance, callback) {
    instance.invokeMethodAsync(callback);
}
```

Comment: As Henk mentioned, you can't do this. StateHasChanged() doesn't work inside a static Method

Comment: @TheBacker thanks for sharing this, it doesn't quite solve my problem but it definitely helps me learn and understand. I really appreciate you taking the time to help.

Comment: This is THE correct answer, the method from Henk is just a workaround. You need to use ` public static  async Task JsMethod` and it works. This is the correct way.

Comment: @NicolaBiada - And how do you hook this up to a service worker.? I think you are overlooking the main problem here.

Comment: @Nicola Biada, yes, you're right. This is the correct answer. I've already provided a link to the asker how to do that the correct Blazor way.

Comment: @Quinton - how do you call this from the worker?  If you worked it out then add a self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `StateHasChanged` after increment.

Look at Microsoft official documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0#state-changes-statehaschanged-1

Comment: As Henk mentioned, you can't do this. StateHasChanged() doesn't work inside a static Method