# Javascript does not update value of a blazor component

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor

I have a problem where I want to pass the value of a CK editor on to a Monaco editor. I can get the value from Monaco to CK but not the other way around. I can also see the value update while debugging but it does not seem to work somehow.

So what i want is when I type something in the CK editor and I press the button to switch to Monaco to have the value of the CK editor in the Monaco editor

This is the javasciprt :

```
function CkEditor(id, readonly, dotNetReference) {
    CKEDITOR.replace(id, {
        customConfig: '../ckeditor/config.js'
    });


    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[id];
    var editorId = editor.id;
    var monacoEditor = document.getElementById("monaco_" + editor.name);
    // Hide toolbar while loading
    editor.on('loaded', () => {
        document.getElementById(editorId + '_top').style.display = 'none';
    });

    editor.on('instanceReady', () => {
        EnableCkEditor(id, readonly);
    });

    editor.on('change', () => {
        var data = editor.getData();
        if (data === '') {
            data = null;
        }
        dotNetReference.invokeMethodAsync('EditorHasChanged', data);
    });

    editor.on('focus', (id) => {
        editor.focusManager.focus();
        document.getElementById(editorId + '_top').style.display = 'block';
        editor.on('afterCommandExec', (event) => {
            var commandName = event.data.name;
            if (commandName === 'enableMonaco') {
                if (monacoIsEnabled === false) {
                    document.getElementById(editorId + '_contents').style.display = 'none';
                    monacoEditor.classList.remove('monaco-wrapper');
                    monacoIsEnabled = true;
                }
                else {
                    editor.setData(monacoEditorData.value);
                    document.getElementById(editorId + '_contents').style.display = 'block';
                    monacoEditor.classList.add('monaco-wrapper');
                    monacoIsEnabled = false;
                }
            }
        });
    });

    editor.on('blur', () => {
        if (!monacoIsEnabled) {
            document.getElementById(editorId + '_top').style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
}

function setCkEditorValue(value) {
    monacoEditorData.value = value;
}

function CkEditorDestroy(id) {
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[id];
    editor.destroy();
    delete editor;
}

function EnableCkEditor(id, readonly) {
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[id];
    if (editor) {
        var editId = editor.id;
        var editorBody = document.getElementById(editId + '_contents');
        if (readonly === true) {
            editorBody.classList.add('disabled_class');
        }
        else {
            editorBody.classList.remove('disabled_class');
        }
    }
}
```

This is the component where it switches between Monaco and CK :

```
@inherits MarkupEditorComponent
@Value
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="ck-editor-wrapper">
        <CkEditor Value="@Value" ValueChanged="@ValueChanged" Readonly="@Readonly" id="@Id"/>
    </div>

    <div class="monaco-wrapper" id="monaco_@Id">
        <CodeEditor Value="@Value" ValueChanged="@ValueChanged" Readonly="@Readonly"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CKEditor.razor

```
@inherits CkEditorComponent

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="ck-editor-wrapper">
        <textarea @attributes="AdditionalAttributes"
                  id="@Id"
                  class="CssClass"
                  value="@Value"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

And as last the CKEditor.razor.cs

```
    public class CkEditorComponent : BaseComponent
    {
        string _id = $"CKEditor{Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToLower().Replace("-", string.Empty)}";

        [Parameter]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public bool Readonly { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public string Id
        {
            get => _id;
            set => _id = value;
        }


        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            await EditorHasChanged(Value);
        }

        protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
        {
            await EnableEditor(Readonly);
            await base.OnParametersSetAsync();
        }

        protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        {
            if (firstRender)
            {
                await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("CkEditor", Id, Readonly, DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));
            }
        }

        [JSInvokable(nameof(EditorHasChanged))]
        public Task EditorHasChanged(string data)
        {
            Value = data;
            ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(data);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("CkEditorDestroy", Id);
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private async Task EnableEditor(bool enabled)
        {
            await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("EnableCkEditor", Id, enabled);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I fixed the issue by not swithing between editors with style but via booleans

Answer (score 0):

You might need to invoke `StateHasChanged()` inside `EditorHasChanged(string data)`. A similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69033634/blazor-not-updating-from-js/69034947#69034947).