# Blazor call window.addEventListener

Tags: blazor

I need to call window.addEventListener in razor method.

```
private void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Disabled && !Readonly)
    {
         window.addEventListener("mousemove",OnMouseMove) // OnMouseMove c# method
         window.addEventListener("mouseup",OnMouseUp)
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this? I could not found any info for getting window in c#

Comment: If you need the window specifically, I don't think there's an option for that in blazor natively. So you'd need to go through jsinterop. I posted an answer on getting the window width with event listeners, which is very similar to what I think you need here. The post was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68963273/blazor-how-to-constantly-get-currentwindow-width/68964761#68964761). Does that help?

Comment: Maybe you can get some ideas from this http://engstromjimmy.se/post/2020-05-25-NewWindow, it's not really the answer to your question, but might help.

Comment: @PLASMAchicken the above link is 404.